# Why won't my bool HttpCookie redirect to a splash page not work correctly?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need the user to visit a splash landing page first (ENTER SITE) `default-splash.aspx` before they see the main `default.aspx` homepage.

Likewise if they have seen it, then it ignores it and stays on the `default.aspx` homepage.

```
bool userVisited = false;
HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["Hoarding"];
if (cookie == null)
{
    cookie = new HttpCookie("Hoarding");
    cookie.Values.Add("userVisitedSplash", true);
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.Days(1);
    cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    this.Page.Response.AppendCookie(cookie);
} else{
     userVisited = cookie.Values["userVisitedSplash"];
}
if(userVisited){
    Response.Redirect("/default.aspx");
} else{
    Response.Redirect("/default-splash.aspx");
}
```

I get an error though, on the line:

```
cookie.Values.Add("userVisitedSplash", true);
```

> CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection.Add(string, string)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 1):

From the error message it's pretty clear that the overload method expect two strings as parameters and you're passing in a `string` and `bool`

so change from

```
cookie.Values.Add("userVisitedSplash", true);
```

To

```
cookie.Values.Add("userVisitedSplash", "true");
```

Then when you read it back then ofcourse convert the `string` `true` to a `bool`

Comment: Thanks @Izzy! But I now get a: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool' here: userVisited = cookie.Values["userVisitedSplash"];`

Answer (score 1):

> The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection.Add(string, string)' has some invalid arguments`

What the above says is that no methods take the parameters you want. It is trying to find a method overload that works for you but it can't. The closest it has found is the one mentioned.

You can see that this takes two strings as parameters whereas what you are passing in is a string and a bool.

To fix it you will need to change your bool to a string. So instead you use:

```
cookie.Values.Add("userVisitedSplash", "true");
```

and then when you are reading it:

```
if (!Boolean.TryParse(cookie.Values["userVisitedSplash"], out userVisited))
{
    userVisited = false;
}
```

This looks for the cookie value, tries to parse it as a boolean and if it fails to parse it then it sets the value to false.

Comment: Thanks Chris! I get a: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool' here now: `userVisited = cookie.Values["userVisitedSplash"];` - Is that what you meant by reading it back??

Comment: Yup, exactly that. My second bit can replace that line of yours

Comment: Thanks Chris. Firefox now says: Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.(I have updated my question). Really appreciate your help here :-)

Comment: @davvv: I think you have strayed into new question territory now. This will be something to do with your redirects rather than a problem with reading and writing cookies. The recommended course of action then would be to ask a new question rather than edit the current one - sticking to one question per question. I would make very sure that you aren't getting stuck in a redirect loop or something like that though.

Answer (score 0):

The argument type is `(string, string)`, you use `("userVisitedSplash", true)` that is a bool type so it show error.